# How to mask specific elements in HL7?

Tags: hl7

Currently I am learning how to work with HL7 and how to parse it in python. Now I was wondering what happens if a value in a HL7 segment contains a pipe sign, e.g. '|'. How is this sign handled? If there is no masking, it would lead to a crash of the HL7 parser. Is there a masking possibility?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\F\

You should read the relevant sections of chapter 2 of the version 2 standard about how escaping works in version 2.

Comment: @arc_lupus you can download the standard(s) from http://www.hl7.org/implement/standards/product_brief.cfm?product_id=185 (registration is for free)

Comment: I think you meant "\F\" rather than "/F/" based on the typical escape character used. Everyone should be aware that escape characters can change with every message so they need to parse out MSH-2 before attempting to process escape sequences in any other fields.

Answer (score 2):

The HL7 structure has defined [escape sequences for the separators](http://www.hl7standards.com/blog/2006/11/02/hl7-escape-sequences/) like `|`.
When you look at a HL7 message, the used five delimiters are right after the MSH:

```
MSH|^~\&
```

- | is the Field separator `F`
- ^ the component separator `S`
- ~ is the repetition separator (for the second level elements) `R`
- **\ is the escape character** `E`
- & is the sub-component separator `T`

So to escape one of the special characters like `|`, you have to take the escape character and then add the defined letter (F,S, etc.)

So in above case, to escape the `|` you would have to put `\F\`. Or escaping the escape character is `\E\`.

If you like you can also change the delimiters after the MSH completely, but I don't recommend that.